# gfortran 7.4 upgradation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gcc, fortran

I am using gfortran 7.3 in Ubuntu 18.04. Now one of the software codes (FLUKA-CERN) requires gfortran 7.4 to run. How to upgrade gfortran 7.4 or higher version 8.2 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gfortran-8](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gfortran-8) for 18.04 is in the repositories. Just install it - `sudo apt install gfortran-8`.